# red black fixup

Tags: c#, insert, red-black-tree, fixup

I have implemented a red black tree, but it doesn't work well. It inserts the nodes not on the correct way. I think it's so because of FixUp. Does anyone know where am i wrong?
When i insert (1, 4, 9, 16). at node 16, it sets the root color to red. then it stops.

I have debugged it, but i wasn't able to find the error myself. I'm new with c# and
further I'm now working for about 3 hours on it. without success.

this is my code:

```
   public void insert(int score, int spelersnummer)
    {
        size++;
        Node z = new Node(score, spelersnummer);
        z.leftChilds++;
        Node y = null;
        Node x = this.root;
        while (x != null)
        {
            y = x;
            if (z.boom < x.boom) // boom staat voor score!
            {
                x.leftChilds++;
                x = x.left;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x.right;
            }

        }

        if (y == null)
        {
            this.root = z;

        }
        else if (z.boom < y.boom)
        {
            y.left = z;
            y.leftChilds++;
            z.parent = y;

        }
        else
        {
            y.right = z;
            z.parent = y;

        }
        // Z heeft automatisch left = null, right = null, color = red
        insertFixUp(z);
    }

    public void insertFixUp(Node z)
    {
        // check of parent bestaat en parent.parent NullPointerException?
        if(z.parent != null && z.parent.parent != null)
        {
            while (z != null && z.parent != null && z.parent.parent != null && !z.parent.isBlack) // ass long as color is not black, thus red
            {
                if (z.parent == z.parent.parent.left)
                {
                    Node y = z.parent.parent.right;
                    if (y != null && !y.isBlack)
                    {
                        z.parent.isBlack = true;
                        y.isBlack = true;
                        z.parent.parent.isBlack = false;
                        z = z.parent.parent;
                    }
                    else if (z == z.parent.right)
                    {
                        z = z.parent;
                        leftRotate(z);
                    }
                    z.parent.isBlack = true;
                    z.parent.parent.isBlack = false;
                    rightRotate(z.parent.parent);

                }
                else
                {

                    Node y = z.parent.parent.left; // left instead of right
                    if (y != null && !y.isBlack) // is red?
                    {
                        z.parent.isBlack = true; // color = black
                        y.isBlack = true; // color = black
                        z.parent.parent.isBlack = false; // color = red
                        z = z.parent.parent;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (z == z.parent.left) // left instead of right
                        {
                            z = z.parent;
                            rightRotate(z);
                        }
                        z.parent.isBlack = true; // color is black
                        z.parent.parent.isBlack = false; // color is red
                        leftRotate(z.parent.parent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void leftRotate(Node x)
    {
        Node y = x.right;
        x.right = y.left;
        if (y != null && y.left != null)
        {
            y.left.parent = x;
        }
        y.parent = x.parent;
        if (x.parent == null)
        {
            root = y;
        }
        else if (x.parent.left != null && x == x.parent.left)
        {
            x.parent.left = y;
        }
        else
        {
            x.parent.right = y;
        }
        y.left = x;

        x.parent = y;

        int lefts;
        lefts = (x.left != null) ? x.left.leftChilds : 0;

        x.leftChilds = lefts + 1;

        lefts= (y.left != null) ? y.left.leftChilds : 0;

        y.leftChilds = lefts + 1;
    }

    public void rightRotate(Node x)
    {
        Node y = x.left;
        x.left = y.right;
        if (y != null && x != null && y.right != null)
        {
            y.right.parent = x;
        }
        y.parent = x.parent;
        if (x.parent == null)
        {
            root = y;
        }
        else if (x.parent.right != null && x == x.parent.right)
        {
            x.parent.right = y;
        }
        else
        {
            x.parent.left = y;
        }
        y.right = x;
        x.parent = y;

        int lefts;
        lefts = (x.left != null) ? x.left.leftChilds : 0;

        x.leftChilds = lefts + 1;

        lefts = (y.left != null) ? y.left.leftChilds : 0;

        y.leftChilds = lefts + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is in C. Hope you can convert it into C#.

```
struct node {
    int key;
    char cl;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *parent;
} *p;

void left_rotate(struct node *r, struct node *q) {
    struct node *y;
    y = q -> right;
    q -> right = y -> left;
    y -> left -> parent = q;
    y -> parent = q -> parent;
    if (q -> parent != NULL) {
        if (q == q -> parent -> left) q -> parent -> left = y;
        else q -> parent -> right = y;
    }
    else p = y;
    y -> left = q;
    q -> parent = y;
}
void right_rotate(struct node *r, struct node *q) {
    struct node *y;
    y = q -> left;
    q -> left = y -> right;
    y -> right -> parent = q;
    y -> parent = q -> parent;
    if (q -> parent != NULL) {
        if (q == q -> parent -> left) q -> parent -> left = y;
        else q -> parent -> right = y;
    }
    else p = y;
    y -> right = q;
    q -> parent = y;
}

void ins_fix(struct node *r, struct node *q) {
    while (q != r &&q -> parent -> cl == 'r') {
        if (q -> parent == q -> parent -> parent -> left) {
            if (q -> parent -> parent -> right -> cl == 'r') {
                q -> parent -> cl = 'b';
                q -> parent -> parent -> cl = 'r';
                q -> parent -> parent -> right -> cl = 'b';
                q = q -> parent -> parent;
            }
            else {
                if (q == q -> parent -> right) {
                    q = q -> parent;
                    left_rotate(p, q);
                }
                q -> parent -> cl = 'b';
                q -> parent -> parent -> cl = 'r';
                right_rotate(p, q -> parent -> parent);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (q -> parent -> parent -> left -> cl == 'r') {
                q -> parent -> cl = 'b';
                q -> parent -> parent -> cl = 'r';
                q -> parent -> parent -> left -> cl = 'b';
                q = q -> parent -> parent;
            }
            else {
                if (q == q -> parent -> left) {
                    q = q -> parent;
                    right_rotate(p, q);
                }
                q -> parent -> cl = 'b';
                q -> parent -> parent -> cl = 'r';
                left_rotate(p, q -> parent -> parent);
            }
        }
    }
    p -> cl = 'b';
}

void add(int num) {
    struct node *temp, *r, *nil;
    temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nil = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> key = num;
    temp -> right = nil;
    temp -> left = nil;
    temp -> parent = NULL;
    temp -> cl = 'r';
    nil -> parent = temp;
    nil -> cl = 'b';
    nil -> right = NULL;
    nil -> left = NULL;
    nil -> key = NULL;
    r = p;
    if (p == NULL || p -> key == NULL) {
        p = temp;
        p -> parent = NULL;
        p -> cl = 'b';
        return;
    }
    while (1) {
        if (r -> left -> key == NULL &&r -> key >= num) {
            r -> left = temp;
            temp -> parent = r;
            ins_fix(p, temp);
            return;
        }
        else if (r -> right -> key == NULL &&r -> keyright = temp;
        temp -> parent = r;
        ins_fix(p, temp);
        return;
        }
        else if (r -> key >= num) r = r -> left;
        else if (r -> keyright;
        }
    }

    struct node *tree_min(struct node *r) {
        while (r -> left -> key != NULL) {
            r = r -> left;
        }
        return r;
    }
    struct node *successor(struct node *r) {
        struct node *y;
        if (r -> right -> key != NULL) return tree_min(r -> right);
        y = r -> parent;
        while (y != NULL &&r == y -> right) {
            r = y;
            y = y -> parent;
        }
        return y;
    }

    void RB_Del_Fix(struct node *r, struct node *x) {
        struct node *w;
        while (x != r &&x -> cl == 'b') {
            if (x == x -> parent -> left) {
                w = x -> parent -> right;
                if (w -> cl == 'r') {
                    w -> cl = 'b';
                    x -> parent -> cl = 'r';
                    left_rotate(p, x -> parent);
                    w = x -> parent -> right;
                } //if closed
                if (w -> left -> cl == 'b' &&w -> right -> cl == 'b') {
                    w -> cl = 'r';
                    x = x -> parent;
                } //if closed
                else {
                    if (w -> right -> cl == 'b') {
                        w -> left -> cl = 'b';
                        w -> cl = 'r';
                        right_rotate(p, w);
                        w = x -> parent -> right;
                    } //if closed
                    w -> cl = x -> parent -> cl;
                    x -> parent -> cl = 'b';
                    w -> right -> cl = 'b';
                    left_rotate(p, x -> parent);
                    x = r;
                } //else closed
            } //if main closed
            else {
                w = x -> parent -> left;
                if (w -> cl == 'r') {
                    w -> cl = 'b';
                    x -> parent -> cl = 'r';
                    right_rotate(p, x -> parent);
                    w = x -> parent -> left;
                } //if closed
                if (w -> left -> cl == 'b' &&w -> right -> cl == 'b') {
                    w -> cl = 'r';
                    x = x -> parent;
                } //if closed
                else {
                    if (w -> left -> cl == 'b') {
                        w -> right -> cl = 'b';
                        w -> cl = 'r';
                        left_rotate(p, w);
                        w = x -> parent -> left;
                    } //if closed
                    w -> cl = x -> parent -> cl;
                    x -> parent -> cl = 'b';
                    w -> left -> cl = 'b';
                    right_rotate(p, x -> parent);
                    x = r;
                } //else closed
            } //else main closed
        } //while closed
        x -> cl = 'b';
    }
    void del(int num) {
        struct node *r, *temp, *y;
        r = p;
        if (r == NULL) {
            printf("Tree is Empty.");
            return;
        }
        while (r -> key != num || r -> key == NULL) {
            if (r -> key == NULL) {
                printf("Number not in Tree.");
                return;
            }
            if (r -> key >= num) r = r -> left;
            else r = r -> right;
        }
        if (r -> left -> key == NULL || r -> right -> key == NULL) y = r;
        else y = successor(r);
        if (y -> left -> key == NULL) temp = y -> right;
        else temp = y -> left;
        temp -> parent = y -> parent;
        if (y -> parent == NULL) p = temp;
        else {
            if (y == y -> parent -> left) y -> parent -> left = temp;
            else y -> parent -> right = temp;
        }
        if (y != r) r -> key = y -> key;
        if (y -> cl == 'b') RB_Del_Fix(p, temp);
    }
    void display(struct node *r) {

        if (r -> key == NULL) return;
        display(r -> left);
        printf(" (%d<->%c) ->", r -> key, r -> cl);
        display(r -> right);

    }

    void main() {

        int i, num;
        clrscr();
        do {
            printf("\n\tEnter the number for following work");
            printf("\n\n\t1=>Enter number to add");
            printf("\n\n\t2=>Display sorted element");
            printf("\n\n\t3=>Enter the number to delete from list\n\n");
            scanf("%d", &i);
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                {
                    printf("\nEnter the number to enter\n");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    add(num);
                    break;
                }

            case 2:
                {
                    display(p);
                    getch();
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    printf("Enter the number");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    del(num);
                    getch();
                    break;
                }

            default:
                exit(1);
            }
            clrscr();
        } while (1);

    }​
```

Hope you will find your solution with this.